# How do I make the iTween plugin work with Unity 2018?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, itween

I got iTween from the asset store to Unity 2018.
iTween included sample code and sample scenes of the content where the cube object moves left and right.
And this worked fine.

I made a new project, made a cube object with the same structure as the sample, attached the sample code.
That is this code.

move.cs

```
enter code here
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveSample: MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start () {
        iTween.MoveBy (gameObject, iTween.Hash ("x", 2, "easeType", 
        "easeInOutExpo", "loopType", "pingPong", "delay", .1));
    }
}
```

Both the object name and the code are the same as the sample project This implementation did not work for some reason and the object did not move left and right.

Does this require something to be done not only in the code but also in scene settings and camera settings?

In the manual, especially iTween calls are not written as required, and there was no need to set up.

Is it a problem unique to Unity 2018?

Please help me.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or is it just not working?  Did you import the iTween package into your new project?

Comment: Thank you.
This problem was solved successfully.

There was no error message.
The iTween package was also successfully installed in the new project.

However, I investigated again why the system did not move.
As a result, I found an interesting specification.

Scripts that call iTween did not provide the correct behavior when attaching directly to an object with Rigidbody and BoxCollider.
To apply to objects with these, we solved the problem by creating a parent object without Rigidbody and BoxCollider and attaching a script calling iTween there.